# How do I include two columns of data in a sum until a certain value is reached, then sum just one column for the remaining rows?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say I have an excel data sheet containing dated entries with an ID and two columns for "hours worked", as well as a table in subsequent columns to summarize the data.

Example:

[image]

In this example, columns A to D are the raw data, columns I and J are the formulas I currently have, and L and M are the final numbers I want to have.

Column I uses

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$15,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($I$1:I1,$A$2:$A$15), 0)),"")}
```

to find unique IDs from column A.

Column J uses

```
=MIN(SUM((SUMIF($A$2:$A$15,I2,$C$2:$C$15))+(SUMIF($A$2:$A$15,I2,$D$2:$D$15))))
```

to sum up all the values of columns C and D for the ID contained in column I.

Essentially what I want to have happen though is for column J to sum up all the values of columns C and D until the sum of those values is 50, and after 50 is reached it should only sum the remaining values in column C.

For example, for ID 12345, it should add 25 + 22 + 3, taking the sum to 50, at which point it should sum the remaining values of column C (the rest of cell C4, ignore cell D5 and just keep summing up column C). The final number for 12345 should be 72.

Note: entries will always be made in chronological order.

Answer (score 0):

Best way I can think of to do this is to use a helper column. With this updated helper formula, the data only needs to be sorted by date.  In cell E2 use this formula and copy down:

```
=MAX(INDEX((A$1:A1=A2)*E$1:E1,))+C2+D2*(MAX(INDEX((A$1:A1=A2)*E$1:E1,))+C2<50)
```

To get the total sum in your summary table, use this formula in cell J2 and copy down:

```
=MAX(INDEX(($A$2:$A$15=I2)*$E$2:$E$15,))
```

You can hide the helper column if preferred, or move it to a different sheet.

Comment: Thanks, that's already super helpful, but I'm sorry - should've mentioned in the original post that the data won't always be sorted by ID and then by date ascending, ID 12345 could go in and input data for 2018-12-25 for example that would show up in row 16. Do you know of a way include reference to the ID in the third IF statement, like to say if(the last value in E for which A is the same as the current row + the current cell > 50 then etc etc )? If not thanks for your help anyways!

Comment: @Kim I have updated the helper formula, that should work for you even if the ID entries are out of order.

Comment: Oh fantastic, that works perfectly. Thanks so much for your help and quick replies!!!